# Change content of the response using reverse proxy

Tags: apache

I am using Apache mod_proxy (reverse proxy) in order to get the contents of a website I own. I want to be able to change the request content and headers before I send it back to client. I searched the web for examples but didn't mange to find any.

is there a method of doing such thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mode_substitute in order to change/replace text on response. But it kind of tricky to use.

```
<Location />
AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
# "foo=k,bar=k" -> "foo/bar=k" 
Substitute "s|foo=(\w+),bar=\1|foo/bar=$1"
</Location>
```